# how can o auto generate for xml for radgridview layout

Tags: xml, layout, radgridview

I`m setting up a Telerik GridView .first of all  I need to create  xml  for saving and loading RadGridView Layout (columns setting , sort , group ,..) in c#. it takes along time to do that.can I have it automatically (auto generate xml for layout) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = "default.xml";
    SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    dialog.Filter ="xml files (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    dialog.Title = "Select a xml file";
    if (dialog.DisplayDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        s = dialog.FileName;
    }
    this.ketticGridView.SaveLayout(s);
}

private void LoadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = "default.xml";
    OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    dialog.Filter ="xml files (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    dialog.Title = "Select a xml file";
    if (dialog.DisplayDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        s = dialog.FileName;
    }
    this.ketticGridView.LoadLayout(s);
}
```